# Proof involving integer squares and parity

Tags: logic, proof-writing, integers, perfect-powers

Original proposition:

> $a$, $b$ and $c$ are integers. Show that if $a^2+b^2=c^2$, at least
>   one of $a$ and $b$ is an even number.

My attempt:

Attemplting proof by contradiction:
Show that there exist a contradiction between the claim that $a^2+b^2=c^2$
...and $a=2k+1, b=2k+1$ where $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a\in\mathbb{Z}$:

Or show:
$$(2k+1)^2+(2l+1)^2\neq c^2$$

I converted the above to:

$$4(k^2+k+l^2+l)+2\neq c^2$$

Perhaps it is possible to show that $4(k^2+k+l^2+l)$ is a perfect square and hence $4(k^2+k+l^2+l)+2$ cannot be a perfect square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume by way of contradiction $a$ and $b$ are odd, as you say we get that $$4(k^2+k+l^2+l)+2=c^2.$$ We have that $c^2$ is even thus $c$ is even, so $c=2m$ for some $m$. We get $$4(k^2+k+l^2+l)+2=4m^2.$$
divide both sides by two: 
$$2(k^2+k+l^2+l)+1=2m^2$$

This  is a contradiction since LHS is odd and RHS is even.

Comment: How exactly is $c$ equal to the sum of two odd integers?

Comment: My bad. c squared is even, thus c is even. I'll make that edit above.